# iOS new build in Xcode 8 GM not found in iTunesconnection

Tags: app-store-connect, xcode8

I can't find my newly uploaded build in iTunesconnect when I click "Select Version to Test" for TestFlight.

[image]

When I tried to upload again, my Xcode shows:

[image]

But where to find my binary? And how to select the newly uploaded build for beta testing for TestFlight? Thanks.

Comment: Builds will be visible from the TestFlight Builds section under TestFlight only after they have been added for testing.

Comment: I am also experiencing this...have you arrived at a solution? I tried re-uploading with new version and build numbers. Also changed target to iOS 10, but that did not help either. The build never shows up on iTunes Connect despite the upload reporting a success.

Comment: @Plastus No. I didn't solve the problem. I tried to upload a few build already. All uploaded successfully. But can't find the build in TestFlight.

Comment: @AmodGokhale Of course I added them for testing. And there are over 20 builds for previous version already. But the new build in Xcode 8 GM could not be found.

Comment: I submitted a support ticket to Apple, will post a comment once I hear back from them.

Comment: @Plastus Thanks. Anyway I solved the issue by reverting back using Xcode 7.3.1.

Comment: @ZhouHao Did you get an email from iTunesConnect about any problems with the new build? I had this issue and it went away after addressing some of them.

Comment: I didn't get any message from iTunesConnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For why can't you find your newly upload versions:

- Check your email.And App Store review my send you an email for `lack of user usage description`.
- Add the key and string value to Info.plist that App Store review ask.

And for why you can't upload your binary file again:

- There is a 1.0.20 existed in iTune connect. So you need let your version +1. such as 1.0.21.
- And every time you try to upload a new version, you must make your version greater than your latest version in iTune connect.
- Then archive and upload it again.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Earlier I had the same issue and got an email from iTunesConnect pointing out some errors in the build I uploaded. It appears you have to address *ALL* the warnings (even though those are supposed to be OK for upload) before the build become visible in iTunesConnect.

In my case, I had warnings about alpha channels in my watch app icons.

Comment: I also has similar situation, in my case I needed to add description about privacy-sensitive data usage. Then I added to `Info.plist` description about usage in `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` key.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I needed that too. :Y